# Event and Objects

Tags: event

I have an array of objects. Instead of me when performing a task asking every object If they have anything to say about that, I would rather like the following:

```
Perform Task

Object #4 Hey, I have something to say about that!
```

And If object #4 says something about that, maybe Object #17 has anything to add up with, because Object #4 did say something. Do you understand?

How do I structure this?

Comment: [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: Note, that Mike is correct, but the language you're working with will directly affect *how* you implement that pattern. Many modern languages have that pattern baked into the language in the form of events (which you have tagged).